# Intellij Idea - как перевести весь java проект на UTF-8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, utf-8

У меня есть старый проект, отличный от кодировки **UTF-8**, мне нужен перевод всего проекта в **UTF-8**.
Работаю в **Intellij Idea**. Проходится каждый файл пере конвертировать.

Настройки проекта выставленные в **UTF-8** - данную проблему **не решают**.

Каждый раз когда **maven** пытается собрать проект, появляются ошибки об исправлении кодировок.
 В проекте, статический контент, жестко задан в классах.

**Обновление**

UTFCastExpress - это отдельная утилита, только не забывайте снимать галочку,
чтобы в начало каждого файла не был установлен BOM.

Может есть плагин, который аккуратно переведет все классы в кодировку **UTF-8** ?

Comment: как минимум java файлы автоматом конвертируются:  File | Settings | Editor | File Encodings выставляем UTF-8 в трех местах

Comment: программу *iconv* не предлагать?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, почему нет?

Comment: File | Settings | Editor | File Encodings - да я высталял, но после запуска maven, сборка не проходила имне пришлось дестяки файлов в Idea сразу же конвертировать, когда это было нужно,  но это можно было делать только вручную...

Answer (score 2):

Есть китайский плагин [Auto Transform Encoding](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10937-auto-transform-encoding/) - утверждается, что автоматом перекодирует текущий файл в UTF-8 и обратно в китайскую кодировку :)

Попробуйте.

Comment: я установил, но не нашел опции которая могла бы перекодировать весь проект.

Comment: Она перекодирует только текущий файл. Пакетное преобразование не предлагается

Answer (score 2):

[Официальный ответ](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206263069-How-to-change-the-encoding-for-whole-project-) от сотрудника Jet Brains:

> Пока такой возможности в самой IDE нет.

На 100% уверен, что утилит для пакетного преобразования кодировки ни одна сотня уже есть.

Comment: Как вы видите работу пакетного преобразователя кодировки? В большинстве случаев невозможно (или очень трудно) провести опознание текущей кодировки файла. Самый надежный способ - визуальный. На этом фоне пакетное преобразование кодировки - это дорога в ад: если среди исходников найдется несколько файлов с уже преобразованной кодировкой - пакетное преобразование изуродует их до неузнаваемости...

Comment: Всё зависит от проекта. Заметил, что в российских проектах русский язык встречается везде, иногда даже в названиях переменных. Это, конечно, усложняет задачу, ведь надо будет конвертировать каждый файл. Если же проект на английском, и языки в отдельном файле лежат, то и преобразовывать почти ничего не потребуется. Главное удостовериться, что проект не представляет собой смесь из нескольких кодировок, например, часть файлов UTF-8, часть Windows-1251. Подключаем проект к VCS, например, Git и после преобразования все неудачные изменения сразу видим и откатываем одним кликом.